# shutil.copy working - but it's looping 10 times?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, copy, shutil

I've written some code to help me backup my photos.
I decided to use the print function to let me know when a file has been backed up, so i can see progress in a simple manner for larger-scale backups.

This script WORKS, however, when I use the print function, i noticed the files were apparently been copying 10 times over for each file of the same filename.

```
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(incomingdir):
            for f in files:
                filepath = os.path.join(subdir,f)
                f_name,f_ext = (os.path.splitext(f))
                f_proj = (f_name.split('_')[0])
                f_cam = (f_name.split('_')[1])
                f_num = (f_name[-2:])

                with open(barcode_csv, 'r') as csv_file:
                    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
                    for row in csv_reader:
                        if f_proj == row[1]:
                            if row[4] == "ROW 4 VALUE":
                                shutil.copy(filepath,backupdir)
                                print(f, " copied to NAS.")
```

the output that I get from this will look like this:

```
1911205D4_CAM01_01.cr2 copied to NAS.
1911205D4_CAM01_01.cr2 copied to NAS.
1911205D4_CAM01_01.cr2 copied to NAS.
1911205D4_CAM01_01.cr2 copied to NAS.
1911205D4_CAM01_01.cr2 copied to NAS.
1911205D4_CAM01_01.cr2 copied to NAS.
1911205D4_CAM01_01.cr2 copied to NAS.
1911205D4_CAM01_01.cr2 copied to NAS.
1911205D4_CAM01_01.cr2 copied to NAS.
1911205D4_CAM01_01.cr2 copied to NAS.
1911205D4_CAM01_02.cr2 copied to NAS.
1911205D4_CAM01_02.cr2 copied to NAS.
1911205D4_CAM01_02.cr2 copied to NAS.
1911205D4_CAM01_02.cr2 copied to NAS.
1911205D4_CAM01_02.cr2 copied to NAS.
1911205D4_CAM01_02.cr2 copied to NAS.
1911205D4_CAM01_02.cr2 copied to NAS.
1911205D4_CAM01_02.cr2 copied to NAS.
1911205D4_CAM01_02.cr2 copied to NAS.
1911205D4_CAM01_02.cr2 copied to NAS.
```

The file copies to the specified directory, as intended. I'm just wondering if this is showing me that it is trying to copy the same file 10 times over and over writes it 9 times? I'm just conscious of large loads on these backups doing so much overwriting and slowing the process down, in turn putting unnecessary strain on my NAS drives.

If I don't use the CSV and just use:

```
print(filepath)
```

it prints fine on screen, showing the singular files only.

Can anyone tell me why it would be printing 10 times over? if it's actually copying 10 times over? and if so, how I would go abotu making sure this only happens once per file?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Kent! Great, thanks so much! I took a look at the particular CSV file it was reading and you're correct. I've scaled that back and removed the duplicate instances. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're copying the file for each row in the file. I assume your file has 10 rows. See if you can figure out how to bring `shutil.copy` out of the loop `for row in csv_reader`. The function [any](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#any) might help but a boolean variable to see whether your condition is satisfied can do the job.